# Float close button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a close button. How do I make it so that the close button hovers as you scroll down the page? Right now it's at the top. 
I want it to make it float to the right (hover the content) as we move down the page.

Comment: If you would like this question to get attention, please add more detail on what you've tried, include some sample code.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `position` property and `bottom`, `right` properties, the element is set in a fixed position as you scroll.

```css
.box {
  height: 1000px;
  position:relative;
}

.floater {
  position: fixed;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="floater">I'm floating</div>
...
</div>
```